# Error in Java : java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\FSSD\Desktop\My Test (Access is denied)

Tags: java, file, windows-7, hidden

I have a java code for copy file from one folder to another folder. I used the following code (I used Windows 7 operating system),

**CopyingFolder.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;


public class CopyingFolder {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File infile=new File("C:\\Users\\FSSD\\Desktop\\My Test");
        File opfile=new File("C:\\Users\\FSSD\\Desktop\\OutPut");
        try {
            copyFile(infile,opfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile)
            throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
            return;
    }
    if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
    }
    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
            source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
    }

}

}
```

While I'm using the above code I got the following Error. Why it will arise? how can I resolved it?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\FSSD\Desktop\My Test (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at CopyingFolder.copyFile(CopyingFolder.java:34)
    at CopyingFolder.main(CopyingFolder.java:18)
```

Comment: are you running this under the FSSD username?

Comment: You sure `My Test` and  `output` are files and not directories

Comment: Is `My Test` a file or a directory? Also, you should not need to call `createNewFile()` explicitly, as creating a `FileOutputStream` will create it, if necessary.

Comment: Is the file `My Test` a file, or a directory? Does some other process have it open for writing?

Comment: @asgs: yes, this is my Username

Comment: @vickirk: Yes these to folder names are Source and Destination respectively

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: My Test is a folder, i need to move destination whatever in it,

Comment: then your code is simply wrong: you should check if it's a directory and recurse into it if it is. Opening a `FileInputStream` only makes sense on files (i.e. non-directories).

Comment: In this case, my solution won't help since he didn't provide a full detail of his file/directory structure. Point of the story: *Assumption is the mother of all f__k-ups* (that's why developers are hired, right?) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access Denied has to do with [User Account Control](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-User-Account-Control). Basically, you're trying to read a file which you don't have permission to read (see the file permission under File properties).

You can see if the file is readable by doing `File.canRead()` method.

```
if (infile.canRead()) {
    //We can read from it.

}
```

To set it to readable, use the `File.setReadable(true)` method.

```
if (!infile.canRead()) {
   infile.setReadable(true);
}
```

Alternatively you can use [`java.io.FilePermission`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/permissions.html) to provide file read permission.

```
FilePermission permission = new FilePermission("C:\\Users\\FSSD\\Desktop\\My Test", "read");
```

Or

```
FilePermission permission = new FilePermission("C:\\Users\\FSSD\\Desktop\\My Test", FilePermission.READ);
```

Comment: i used your code, i can't get the correct output. i think, i make the mistake when i add this..if you don't mind change my code as per your code please,

Comment: @BenDennison, I don't know your directory structure and what you're doing. Give me more info as to what the code is doing.

Comment: My requirement is,i want to move a file form one folder to another folder. That is "C:/MyTest",in MyTest folder i has a file name "ExampleFile.file". Here i must move "ExampleFile.java" to "C:/OutPut" folder. if it possible to do this using my code else any alternate way to do this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Then try changing `infile` to include the **full** file name (with path) as follows: `File infile=new File("C:\\Users\\FSSD\\Desktop\\My Test\\Example.java");` and see if it works. Also, mine will probably work since I have administrator access to all my data in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would put my files in a directory that is not under user/...

Try to put your files in  c:/mytest/