# java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\abcd (Access is denied)

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am trying to transfer the directory to sftp remote server.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class FolderTransfer {

    public FolderTransfer() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String SFTPHOST = "hostname";
        int SFTPPORT = 22;
        String SFTPUSER = "admin";
        String SFTPPASS = "password";
        String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/cygdrive/c/Users/admin";

        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
            session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\abcd\\");
            channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
            System.out.println("done....");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

But i am getting the error like
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\admin\Desktop\abcd (Access is denied)
How i can solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in Java : java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\FSSD\Desktop\My Test (Access is denied)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093683/error-in-java-java-io-filenotfoundexception-c-users-fssd-desktop-my-test-ac)

Comment: You can't open a folder with a **File**InputStream.

Comment: abcd is a directory not a file..

Comment: @danyal: yeah but i need to transfer that  whole folder to server...

Comment: zip the folder and transfer it..or iterate over the files and send one by one..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo:How i can iteratre?

Comment: @uneducated_Brilliant answered that :)

Comment: @Danyal Sandeelo:i have followed the same..but resulting error is Access Denied..

Comment: this is because you are probably accessing another user ,, can you place in D drive and try?

Comment: i did ..but showing same...should i need to change anything in abcd folder security option?

Answer (score 0):

abcd is not a file, it is a directory. Compress the directory and send as a file or get all the files and send them one by one

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
    System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  }
}
```